# how do I make a simple payment portal for accepting monero payments on my website, without third party service?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, vps

I run a brick and mortar shop and I really like the gui wallets merchent view page. I would like to add similar functionality to my website, but I have no idea how to do that.

Its a simple one page website hosted on a debain 10 VPS with apache. No java or css or whatever. Just product discriptions and links to pay with paypal.

I do have the monero cli wallet installed on the vps but i dont know how to make the website talk to it. Is there something that I can add to my website which generates a new address each time a user clicks a button?

All of the solutions I have seen (including all the ones listed at https://web.getmonero.org/community/merchants/#libraries) require some third party or service that I not part of (like the wordpress/globee plugins) or their documentation is way too complicated for me to follow, or just nonexsistent. they seem to assume people using them know how to code (like the php libraries).

ideall process would be

```
1. user inputs their info into form

2. user clicks pay with xmr

3. unique payment code/subadress/whatever is generated

4. user pays

5.after 1 confirmation i get a notification to send out product
```

I can follow guides and processes but I don't want to have to write my own scripts from scratch or spend hours troubleshooting. I can ssh into my vps, cd around directories and apt install and git clone and copy paste and thats about it.

Comment: There's no turnkey "copy-paste" solution to your question. Your level of knowledge will require you to contract with some kind of developer to implement your solution.